# problem in getting cell value from grid view

Tags: c#, gridview, asp.net-2.0

I want to get the cell value from a grid view.

I am using the following code but it produces an error.

#### Code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ((GridView)TeamMemberGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).ToString();
```

#### Note:

`@ProjectCode` is one of the fields in the grid view.

Comment: 1. Which programming language? 2. what "grid view"? Google returns 10 million results for "grid view". 3. Put the exact error message in your question.

Comment: 1. ASP.NET with c#
2 error is 
    " Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Answer (score 1):

As Leppie has already stated, the TableCell object exposes a `Text` property which will give you access to the text contents of a TableCell.

What you need to understand is that the `TeamMemberGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1]` statement **returns a TableCell object** referencing the specified TableCell in your GridView.

So your statement becomes :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TeamMemberGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
```

Finally, the reason for the cast seems unclear in your statement so I removed that.

Answer (score 0):

`TableCell` has a `Text` property.

Comment: how to get grid view cell value

Answer (score 0):

I think its:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ((GridView)TeamMemberGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
```

Comment: I guess the next question would therefore be... What is the error produced?!